# Generating Vertices in OpenGL ES 2.0 Vertex Shader

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I am trying to draw a triangle with three vertices a,b,c. Typically, i would have these three vertex co-ordinates in an array and pass it as an attribute to my vertex shader.

But , is it possible to generate these vertex co-ordinates within the vertex shader itself rather than passing as an attribute (i.e. per vertex co-ordinate value for corresponding vertex position). If yes, any sample program to support it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create variables in vertex shader and pass it to fragment shader. An example:

**Vertex shader**

```
precision highp float;

uniform float u_time;
uniform float u_textureSize;
uniform mat4  u_mvpMatrix;                   

attribute vec4 a_position;

// This will be passed into the fragment shader.
varying vec2 v_textureCoordinate0;

void main()                                 
{
    // Create texture coordinate
    v_textureCoordinate0 = a_position.xy / u_textureSize;

    gl_Position = u_mvpMatrix * a_position;
}
```

And the **fragment shader**:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform float   u_time;
uniform float   u_pixel_amount;
uniform sampler2D u_texture0;   

// Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.
varying vec2 v_textureCoordinate0;

void main(void)
{       
    vec2 size = vec2( 1.0 / u_pixel_amount, 1.0 / u_pixel_amount);    
    vec2 uv = v_textureCoordinate0 - mod(v_textureCoordinate0,size);    
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( u_texture0, uv );    
    gl_FragColor.a=1.0;
}
```

How you can see, vector 2D named **v_textureCoordinate0** is created in vertex shader and its interpolated value is used in fragment shader.

I hope it help you.

Comment: Sorry, but what i wanted was generation of a_textureCoordinate0 within the vertex shader rather than passing it as an attribute

Comment: You can use built-in variable or constant to valorize v_textureCoordinate0 too. I update example code.

Comment: My implementation seems to be working now, will paste the code sometime soon.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to post your snippet somewhere @udayshukla ? I'm interested in the problem too..